# HTTP Request with .key and .cer without https scheme

Tags: java, http, soap, curl, ssl

I am developing a java client where I need to send some soap xml to server. Server is running on http scheme but it requires request to be encrypted as is there in case of https. I have generated .cer and .key files on my server and same has been imported on server side as well. Now when I tries to execute below command to send request to server, it is not working.

My soap xml is there in text.txt

```
curl -vX POST -d @test.txt http://test.com:98/wcflib-tc/service.svc 
--header "Content-Type:application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8;" 
--cert /myserver/certs/server.crt 
--key  /myserver/certs/server.key

* About to connect() to test.com port 98 (#0)    
*   Trying 172.27.655.65... connected
* Connected to test.com (172.27.655.65) port 98 (#0)
> POST /wcflib-tc/service.svc HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.12.9.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.2.2
> Host: test.com:98
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8;
> Content-Length: 962
>

< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
< X-Powered-By: Programmer's tears
< Date: Mon, 18 Nov 2013 05:26:18 GMT
< Content-Length: 576
<
* Connection #0 to host test.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<s:Header><a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</a:Action></s:Header>       
<s:Body><s:Fault><s:Code><s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value> 
<s:Subcode><s:Value xmlns:a="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
a:InvalidSecurity</s:Value></s:Subcode></s:Code>
<s:Reason><s:Text xml:lang="en-US">
An error occurred when verifying security
for the message.</s:Text></s:Reason>
```

Please let me know the solution. Otherwise let me know how to handle http request with .key and .cer file using any java api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clue is in `http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd` - you need to use WS-Security. Bore yourself to tears reading the specs here https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=wss